# Does this gem exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I currently need to store in database an id, representing an index in a specific constant array. I'm always using methods like this, generated by a concern.

```
class Foo
  ARY = [ :a :b, :c ]

  def bar
    return ARY[self.bar_id]
  end

  def bar=(value)
    return self.bar_id=ARY.index(value)
  end

  scope :a, -> { where(:bar_id => ARY.index(:a)) }
  scope :b, -> { where(:bar_id => ARY.index(:b)) }
  scope :c, -> { where(:bar_id => ARY.index(:c)) }

  def a?
    return bar == :a
  end
  def b?
    return bar == :b
  end
  def c?
    return bar == :c
  end

end
```

Does a gem doing this exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [simple_enum](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum) gem your class becomes

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  as_enum :bar, [:a, :b, :c], source: :bar_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord has built-in support for this. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html